# My app crashes before running in the emulator

Tags: android

I am building my app and when I run it with  emulator/my phone its crash before opening even. Here is the code:

**Mainactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.marvelx.phonecall.MainActivity">

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="105dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.marvelx.phonecall">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.marvelx.phonecall;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     EditText[] number;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        number= new EditText[3];
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       number[0]= findViewById(R.id.et1);
        number[1]= findViewById(R.id.et2);
        number[2]= findViewById(R.id.et3);

    }

    public void send(View v) {
        Call();
    }
    int index = 0;

    public void Call(){

         String num = number[index].getText().toString();

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+num));
         startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

I've tried rebuilding, cleaning the Project and research on Google, Stack, and Youtube without success.

Where i can also upload the Logcat?

Comment: "where i can also upload the Logcat?" - You can [edit] your question to add it there. For starters, remove the `<uses-permission>` element from the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: thank you,but to preforem dail i dont have to use the permission?

Comment: Permissions belong in the manifest, not in layout files. You already have it in the manifest, so just remove it from the layout.

Comment: ok!, thank you mike !

Comment: @Dilip Please, do not alter the OP's code or XML, other than to fix the formatting.

Comment: Hey @MikeM I am not change his code just removed permission from the layout file.

Comment: @Dilip That is exactly what I'm talking about. That line is pertinent to the question, and it needs to be there. Don't add or remove content from code or XML. Only fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` from your MainActivity.xml file.  I tested it on my side, and it fixed the problem.

Also, consider changing `Intent.ACTION_CALL` into `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`.  The dial action doesn't require the permission you would remove.

Comment: dosent Intent.ACTION_CALL need to work with the permission?